# Make a link clickable through div:before

Tags: css, html, click-through

I would like to click through a :before div.
This is my code:

```
/*CSS*/
#main {
    float:left;
    width:calc(70% - 4px);
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    left:calc(15% - 4.5px);
    margin-top:40px;
}

#main:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:-3px;
    left:-3px;
    right:-3px;
    bottom:-3px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
<!--html-->     
<div id="main">
    <h3>Inhoudsopgave (sitemap)</h3>
        <ul style="text-align:left;">
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="inhoudsopgave.html">Inhoudsopgave</a></li>
            <li><a href="interviews.html">Interviews</a>
        <ul>
            <li>FC Den Bosch</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
              <li>Resultaten</li>
              <li>Conclusie</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are multiple links in the div, but because of the :before in the css file, i can't click on it. As you can see, I tried pointer-events but that didn't help.

I need the :before div (as far as i know) because i want to make a double-lined border. The border on #main is slightly larger than the border on the :before, which makes it a double lined border.

Comment: pseudo element is out of DOM-Tree so you cannot make clickable to that.

Comment: You're also missing correct ul and li tags.

Comment: @OmgImAlexis what tags am i missing? I suppose you suggest that the "interviews" li is not closed, but i close this li underneath the "FC Den Bosch" li.

Comment: You've got ul's that don't end and li's in places where they shouldn't be.. None of this would validate and I'm not even sure if it's show up correctly in a browser.